# Confusion in close loop block diagram

Tags: control, control-system

I am studying chapter 4 of Dorf title Modern Control systems(11 edition)

I am trying to use MATLAB or Labview to implement block diagram for open loop control systems for speed control of an armature controlled DC motor

I have also attached the figure of book

I understand that the rightmost block \$\frac{1}{js+b}\$ will be in feedback with \$K_b\$ block.
But what will be the relation of feedback block \$K_b\$ with the two left most blocks (**\$1/R_a\$ and \$K_m\$ in series**) ?? Independent individual feedback relation with the two left most blocks (**\$1/R_a\$ and \$K_m\$ in series**)  or the series combination of rightmost block \$\frac{1}{js+b}\$ **and** \$K_b\$ will be in feedback with the two left most blocks (**\$1/R_a\$ and \$K_m\$ in series**)

[image: snapshot of block diagram]

Answer (score 1):

The term "feeedback" is used when a portion of the output signal is coupled back to the input. Hence, it is important to verify the input node.

In your circuit, we have two inputs: A reference input v(s) and a disturbance input T(s) and two corresponding transfer functions H1=out/v(s) and H2=out/T(s).

- For H1 the forward gain Hf is the product of all three forward acting blocks with the feedback block Kb.
- For H2 the forward gain Hf is only the most right block with a feedback chain consisting of all the remaining three blocks.
- The **closed-loop gain** in both cases is **Hf/(1+loop gain)**. The loop gain is the same in both cases; it is the product of all four transfer functions.